# How to convert mySQL datetime returned in a JSON object to a Swift date?

Tags: mysql, json, swift, date, datetime

I have a JSON object that has a mySQL datetime inside of it that I need to decode in Swift and compare it to another date. How can I convert this mySQL datetime into a Swift date?

Below is what is returned in the JSON object:

```
{"startDate": "Sun, 02 Aug 2020 00:00:00 GMT"}
```

This is how we've tried to decode it:

```
struct jsonDate: Codable {
    let startDate: String
}

let tempDate = try JSONDecoder().decode(jsonDate.self, from: data)
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
let previousSunday = dateFormatter.date(from: tempDate.startDate)!
```

Comment: Our issue is decoding the datetime. We've tried decoding it as a Swift date and as a String but neither has worked.

Comment: You can take a look at: https://nsdateformatter.com

Comment: No idea why you have that localized date string in JSON. I highly recommend you discuss with the one who provided the JSON to you, provide a UNIX timestamp. which can be more accurate and easy to convert.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the string you provide for the JSON, the date format you're setting on the formatter is incorrect. The format you set matches ISO-8601-formatted strings, like

```
2020-02-08 00:00:00 Z
```

but your string would require a format like

```
E, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss ZZZZ
```

instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can parse your date string using `DateFormatter` and setting a correct `dateFormat`:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "E, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"
let previousSunday = dateFormatter.date(from: tempDate.startDate)!
```

You can take a look at this site [NSDateFormatter.com](https://nsdateformatter.com) for more information.

---

**Note**

I recommend not to force-unwrap optionals:

```
dateFormatter.date(from: tempDate.startDate)! // crash if `nil`
```

and provide a default value instead or throw an error:

```
if let previousSunday = dateFormatter.date(from: tempDate.startDate) {
    // previousSunday is valid
} else {
    // throw an error etc.
}
```